# Sessions class With assoc-array - practicing

Tags: php, html

I try to dealing with sessions.. including arrays before moving to "database".

Sessions class.file

```
<?php
session_start();
class Sessions {


public static function ready($name){
  return isset($_SESSION[$name]) ? true : false;
}
    public static function get($name){
      if(isset($_SESSION[$name])){
        return $_SESSION[$name];
      }else {
        return false;
      }
      }

public static function set($name, $val = []){
  return $_SESSION[$name] = $val;

}

    public static function des($name){
      if(self::ready($name)){
       unset($_SESSION[$name]);
      }

    }

}
```

index.php file

```
<?php

include_once "Sessions.php";

const BR = '<br>';

$er = [];
$data = array([
    'id'=> '1',
    'username'=> 'user1',
    'password'=>'123456'
  ],
  [
    'id'=> '2',
    'username'=> 'user2',
    'password'=>'654321'
  ]
);

//submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // Error Msgs
$er[] = "Not found in array";
// Forms Inputs
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//fetch users in array
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if(in_array($username, $value)){
    if( $username == $value['username'] && $password == $value['password'] ){
      $uid = $value['id'];
      $unm = $value['username'];
      //Sessions class
      Sessions::set('id', $uid);
      Sessions::set('username', $unm );
      // Error Msgs
     unset($er[0]);
    }
}
  }
}


?>
<?php
//Sessions class
$susername = Sessions::ready('username');
$sid = Sessions::ready('id');
if( $susername AND $sid) { ?>
<?$sid?>
<?$susername?>
<?=BR.Sessions::get('username').BR?>
<?=BR.Sessions::get('id').BR?>
<br>
<a href='log.php'>Out</a>
<br>
<? if( isset( $er[0] ) ) { echo $er[0];}else { unset( $er[0] ); } ?>

<form  method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="">
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

logout.php file

```
<?php
include_once "Sessions.php";
Sessions::des('username');
Sessions::des('id');
header("Location:session.php");
?>
```

Is it good for beginner..! is there something wrong..! is there better way for that messy code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `return isset($_SESSION[$name]) ? true : false;` is more succintly written as:

  ```
  return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
  ```

  The boolean evaluation of `isset()` is all you need.
- You can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) to tight up:

  ```
  if(isset($_SESSION[$name])){
      return $_SESSION[$name];
  }else {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  Into:

  ```
  return $_SESSION[$name] ?? false;
  ```
- You never need to check if a variable exists before calling `unset()`. If the variable doesn't exist, the script smoothly, silently continues processing as usual.
- The tabbing of your code is needing a fair amount of tender loving care.  Use 4 spaces to indent where necessary. PSR standards are available for everyone's benefit.
- I don't think I support the technique of pushing an error message into an array pre-emptively, then removing the element if everything passes.  Add a descriptive error to the error array ONLY if an error is detected.
- If you are not going to use a variable (e.g. `$key` in your loop), then don't bother declaring it.
- I realize this is just practice, but try to store only `id` values in session data if your project permits it.  There is such a thing as Session Hijacking -- it may be an extreme scenario, but it is best to avoid storing any "real world" identifying data in session arrays.
- I generally avoid using `AND` and `OR` in my `if` expressions so that I am never tripped up by a fringe "precedence" gotcha.
- If you want to display boolean values for diagnostics, I recommend `var_export()`.
- Finally, read about how to destroy a session on logout: [PHP Session Destroy on Log Out Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001702/php-session-destroy-on-log-out-button)